# How to add a Delete button to django.forms generated form?

Tags: python, django

How to add a  Delete button to [django.forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) generated edit form (note, NOT admin)?

Its very easy to add a delete view on (`/app/model/<id>/delete/` etc) but how to add a "Delete" button alongside the generated form?

I've got to be missing something easy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a submit button to the template, set the name as 'delete', check in your view if it was clicked:

```
if request.POST.get('delete'):
    obj.delete()
```

Comment: I was expecting some way of doing this automagically via forms.py Meta: or similar?

Comment: Django forms dont do buttons. Its upto you to put them in the template. There are pluggable apps (django-uni-form) though that will allow you to create forms with buttons in the form definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some generic form like this

```
class DeletableModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Model form that allows you to delete the object
    """
    delete = forms.BooleanField(
        initial=False,
        help_text=_('Check this to delete this object')
    )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if self.cleaned_data['delete']:
            return self.instance.delete()
        return super(DeletableModelForm, self).save()
```

And then you could restyle the checkbox to look like button. 
But you are probably better of with normal button with name...